# Tkinter var trace

Tags: python, forms, class, tkinter, trace

I'm writing code creating a class that represents a group form (ArticoloForm), taking dynamically attributes from a dictionary passed in **init** method.
When group form button is pressed, an article is created and added to attribute articles of this class and IntVar articleId is increased

Another class (ArticlesDisplyed) list articles of ArticoloForm instances that are passed in its **init** method.
When variable articleId changes in one of the ArticoloForm instances passed, ArticlesDisplayed do something in its **draw** method, thanks to traces in its updateList method.

Here the classes:

```
class ArticoloForm:

    articleList = {}

    def __init__(self, container, gridRow, gridColumn, className, attributes):
        self.container = container
        self.gridRow = gridRow
        self.gridColumn = gridColumn
        self.className = className
        if type(attributes) == dict:
            self.attributes = attributes

    def _getValues_(self, event):
        # metodo che recupera i valori dei widget di una singola form e li inserisce nel dizionario widgetsValues. Descrive un articolo.
        widgetsValues = {}

        #per ogni attributo nel dizionario degli attributi
        for attr in self.attributes:
            #se il dizionario ha la chiave widget e quindi c'è un widget
            if self.attributes[attr].has_key('widget'):
                #se il widget è diverso da 'text' prende il valore in un modo, altrimenti in un altro, siccome il widget text ha bisogno di indici di inizio e fine
                if self.attributes[attr]['type'] != "Text":
                    widgetsValues[attr] = self.attributes[attr]['widget'].get()
                else:
                    widgetsValues[attr] = self.attributes[attr]['widget'].get("1.0", "end-1c")      
        widgetsValues['articleType'] = str(self.className).split(".")[1]
        #~ inserisce nel dizionario che contiene la lista degli articoli creati da questa form il nuovo articolo. La chiave è un id IntVar di cui monitoro le modifiche
        self.articleList[self.articleId.get() + 1] = widgetsValues
        temp = self.articleId.get()
        self.articleId.set(temp + 1)
        #~ print "ID:    " + str(self.articleId.get()) + "\n\n"

    def _bindAddArticle_(self):
        for attr in self.attributes:
            if self.attributes[attr].has_key('button'):
                self.attributes[attr]['button'].bind("<Button-1>", self._getValues_)

    def draw(self):
        # etichetta che specifica il tipo di articolo
        self.articleId = IntVar()
        self.articleId.set(0)
        Label(self.container, text="Aggiunta " + str(self.className.__name__), font="bold").grid(row=self.gridRow, column=self.gridColumn, columnspan=2)        
        # disegno gli attributi prendendo i dati dal dizionario e aggiungendo il widget da disegnare al dizionario per poterlo richiamare negli events
        for attr in self.attributes.iterkeys():
            if self.attributes[attr]['type'] == 'Combobox':
                Label(self.container, text=attr).grid(row=self.gridRow + self.attributes[attr]['row'], column=self.gridColumn)
                #~ default = StringVar(self.container)  
                #~ default.set("Seleziona...")
                self.attributes[attr]['widget'] = Combobox(self.container)
                self.attributes[attr]['widget']['values'] = self.attributes[attr]['values']
            elif self.attributes[attr]['type'] == 'Text':
                Label(self.container, text=attr).grid(row=self.gridRow + self.attributes[attr]['row'], column=self.gridColumn)
                self.attributes[attr]['widget'] = Text(self.container, width=self.attributes[attr]['width'], height=self.attributes[attr]['height'])
            elif self.attributes[attr]['type'] == 'Entry':
                Label(self.container, text=attr).grid(row=self.gridRow + self.attributes[attr]['row'], column=self.gridColumn)
                self.attributes[attr]['widget'] = Entry(self.container)
            if self.attributes[attr].has_key('widget'):
                self.attributes[attr]['widget'].grid(row=self.gridRow + self.attributes[attr]['row'], column=self.gridColumn+1)
            if self.attributes[attr]['type'] == 'Button':
                self.attributes[attr]['button'] = Button(self.container, text="Aggiungi "+ str(self.className.__name__))
                self.attributes[attr]['button'].grid(row=self.gridRow + self.attributes[attr]['row'], column=self.gridColumn+1)
            #Separator(self.container, orient=VERTICAL).grid(row=self.gridRow-1, column=self.gridColumn, rowspan=len(self.attributes.keys()), sticky='sn')
            self._bindAddArticle_()

    #~ def removeArticle(self, event, articleId):   TODO
        #~ self.articleList.pop(articleId, None)
        #~ temp = self.articleId.get()
        #~ self.articleId.set(temp - 1)

######################################################################################

class ArticlesDisplayed:

#~ labels:  CONTIENE TUTTI I GRUPPI DI ETICHETTE E BOTTONI. OGNI ETICHETTA E' UN ARTICOLO AGGIUNTO ALL'ORDINE. LA CHIAVE DI OGNI ARTICOLO CORRISPONDE ALL'ARTICLEID DELLA CLASSE ARTICOLOFORM 
#~ articleForm: L'ISTANZA DI UNA FORM CREATA 

    labelsGroup = {}

    def __init__(self, container, gridRow, gridColumn, articleForms=[]):
        self.container = container
        self.gridRow = gridRow
        self.gridColumn = gridColumn
        self.articleForms = articleForms

    def updateList(self):
        traceIdList = {}
        i = 0
        for articleForm in self.articleForms:
            traceIdList[i] = articleForm.articleId
            traceIdList[i].trace("r", self.__draw__)
            i += 1

    def __draw__(self, event, d, s):
        print "we " + str(self.articleForms[0].articleId.get())
```

So with my main code:

```
# draw five group forms
scarpaAttrs = {'colore' : {'row' : 1, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Scarpe.possibiliColori}, 
'modello' : {'row' : 2, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Scarpe.possibiliModelli},
'marca' : {'row' : 3, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Scarpe.possibiliMarche},
'descrizione' : {'row' : 4, 'type' : 'Text', 'width' : 25, 'height' : 3},
'Aggiungi' : {'row' : 5, 'type' : 'Button'}}
scarpaForm = ArticoloForm(mainframe, 5, 0, Scarpe, scarpaAttrs)
scarpaForm.draw()

borsaAttrs = {'colore' : {'row' : 1, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Borsa.possibiliColori}, 
'modello' : {'row' : 2, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Borsa.possibiliModelli},
'marca' : {'row' : 3, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Borsa.possibiliMarche},
'descrizione' : {'row' : 4, 'type' : 'Text', 'width' : 25, 'height' : 3},
'Aggiungi' : {'row' : 5, 'type' : 'Button'}}
borsaForm = ArticoloForm(mainframe, 5, 3, Borsa, borsaAttrs)
borsaForm.draw()

cinturaAttrs = {'colore' : {'row' : 1, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Cintura.possibiliColori}, 
'modello' : {'row' : 2, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Cintura.possibiliModelli},
'marca' : {'row' : 3, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Cintura.possibiliMarche},
'descrizione' : {'row' : 4, 'type' : 'Text', 'width' : 25, 'height' : 3},
'Aggiungi' : {'row' : 5, 'type' : 'Button'}}
cinturaForm = ArticoloForm(mainframe, 5, 6, Cintura, cinturaAttrs)
cinturaForm.draw()

giaccaAttrs = {'colore' : {'row' : 1, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Giacca.possibiliColori}, 
'modello' : {'row' : 2, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Giacca.possibiliModelli},
'marca' : {'row' : 3, 'type' : 'Combobox', 'values' : Giacca.possibiliMarche},
'descrizione' : {'row' : 4, 'type' : 'Text', 'width' : 25, 'height' : 3},
'Aggiungi' : {'row' : 5, 'type' : 'Button'}}
giaccaForm = ArticoloForm(mainframe, 5, 9, Giacca, giaccaAttrs)
giaccaForm.draw()

articoloAttrs = {'colore' : {'row' : 1, 'type' : 'Entry', 'values' : Articolo.possibiliColori}, 
'modello' : {'row' : 2, 'type' : 'Entry'},
'marca' : {'row' : 3, 'type' : 'Entry'},
'descrizione' : {'row' : 4, 'type' : 'Text', 'width' : 25, 'height' : 3},
'Aggiungi' : {'row' : 5, 'type' : 'Button'}}

articoloForm = ArticoloForm(mainframe, 5, 13, Articolo, articoloAttrs)
articoloForm.draw()
```

Then I call ArticlesDisplayed to display added articles.

```
articles = ArticlesDisplayed(mainframe, 16, 0, articleForms=[scarpaForm, borsaForm, giaccaForm, cinturaForm])
articles.updateList()
```

Now, in order to do debug for my issue, I make the **draw** method of ArticlesDisplayed print "we" and the problem is that "we" is printed two time when I add a single article clicking button of one group form.
But articleId changes only once when a button is clicked, so **draw** method of ArticlesDisplayed should be called once and print only one "we +" str(articleId.get()). In addition to my problem, first time I click a button to add an article, is printed "we 0", but articleId should be increased to 1.

Can help me? If it's not so clear can ask and I'll try to formulate my question in a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Please review this and amend accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is just way too much code to wade through. Please try to condense it down as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!! I feel so stupid. I changed the first parameter passed to trace method for those variable from 'r' to 'w'. I want to trace writing operations, not reading...

Done